# Twig Assetic Lazy file output?

Tags: php, twig, lazy-evaluation, assetic

I am preparing a php library that I have developed individually. I use assig to compress twig, css and js files for the theme system in the library.

If you will be responsible for knowledgeable developers; Static file output problem does not occur when using GlobAsset or FileAsset. I get an error when I use twig with filter assetic. Two I've been working on this for days, but I have not found the solution.

I share your source code with you, I hope you can help.

**Template.php**

```
static::$fileSystem = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem();
static::$tpl = new Twig_Environment(static::$fileSystem, $configArr);

$am = new AssetManager();
$fm = new FilterManager();
$fm->set('cssrewrite', new CssRewriteFilter());

static::$factory = new AssetFactory('C:/WinNMP/WWW/bulk/css/');
static::$factory->setAssetManager($am);
static::$factory->setFilterManager($fm);
static::$factory->setDebug(true);
static::$factory->addWorker(new AssetVersionWorker('1.0.0'));
//static::$factory->addWorker(new CacheBustingWorker());

$am = new LazyAssetManager(static::$factory);

// enable loading assets from twig templates, caching the formulae
$am->setLoader('twig', new TwigCachingFormulaLoader(static::$tpl));
$templates = array($dir.self::HtmlDir.'/content.twig');
// loop through all your templates
foreach ($templates as $template) {
    $resource = new TwigResource(static::$fileSystem, $template);
    $am->addResource($resource, 'twig');
}

$writer = new PersistentAssetWriter(Config::get('cache.assets.frontend'));
$writer->writeManagerAssets($am);

static::$tpl->addExtension(new AsseticExtension(static::$factory));
```

**header.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
{% block head %}
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <meta name="language" content="tr" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{settings.settingKeywords}}" />
    <meta name="description" content="{{settings.settingDescription}}" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow, odp" />
    <meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow, odp" />
    <base href="{{settings.siteHostAdress}}/"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{PIP('favicon.ico', 'site')}}">
    {% block stylesheets %}
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">
          {% stylesheets 
          'C:/WinNMP/WWW/bulk/css/*'
          filter='cssrewrite' 
          output='css/all.css'
          %}
            <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
          {% endstylesheets %}

    {% endblock %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var settings = {{ settingsJson|json_encode() }};
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

**This is the error:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Unable to register extension "assetic" as extensions have already been initialized.' in C:\WinNMP\WWW\bulk\Libs\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php:937 Stack trace: #0 C:\WinNMP\WWW\bulk\Kernel\Core\Template.php(118): Twig_Environment->addExtension(Object(Assetic\Extension\Twig\AsseticExtension)) #1 C:\WinNMP\WWW\bulk\Kernel\Interview\Frontview.php(94): Core\Template::addPath('c:/winnmp/www/b...') #2 C:\WinNMP\WWW\bulk\App\Interview\Frontface\PageNotFound.php(13): Interview\Frontview->__construct() #3 C:\WinNMP\WWW\bulk\Kernel\Rewrite.php(58): Frontface\PageNotFound->__construct() #4 C:\WinNMP\WWW\bulk\Kernel\App.php(26): Rewrite::requestMap() #5 C:\WinNMP\WWW\bulk\index.php(31): App::Run() #6 {main} thrown in C:\WinNMP\WWW\bulk\Libs\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php on line 937
```

Comment: Just remove `static::$tpl->addExtension(new AsseticExtension(static::$factory));`?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unexpected "stylesheets" tag (expecting closing tag for the "block" tag

Comment: The node `stylesheets`is not known then

Comment: If you can not add Assetic Extension this error is getting. Output I am getting an error when I print the file. I can print as a dump but it does not work because the file does not print.

Comment: Yes, but the first error u got statted it's already registered

Comment: By the way, I can not use the symfony library. Could this be the cause of the error?

Comment: Do you have any information on this?